# After two sequentials requests the PostMan response object contains response of first request

Tags: javascript, postman

After a Post request I want to save some properties from two different Get Requests as environment variables.

In the codeline extracting data from the second request PostMan is giving a "TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined".

The reason is that I'm expecting an array in the response of the second request and there isn't. By logging to the console I noticed that although the response of the second request is showing this array the PostMan response object contains the response of the first request. I tried to figure out why but can't find a clue. Here's my code:

```
    var request1 = "The first request"

    pm.sendRequest(request1, function () 
    {
       var jsonData1 = pm.response.json();
       pm.environment.set("CCIdNewBranch", jsonData1.id);  
    });

    var request2 = "The second request"

    pm.sendRequest(request2, function () 
    {
       var jsonData2  = pm.response.json();
    
       for (var i = 0; i < jsonData2.data.length; i++) 
       {
          if (jsonData2.data[i].rdcNumber == pm.environment.get("RdcNNewBranch"))
          {
            pm.environment.set ("DmsIIdNewBranch",jsonData2.data[i].dmsInstanceId)
            break
          }; 
       }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason I put this requests in the Testscript of another request is to reduce the number of request in my collection.

Now I realise that the pm.sendRequest is by nature an asynchronues request and that you have no control over the order in which different requests are executed. So it's better not to have no more then one pm.sendRequest method in your TestScript.

Comment: `pm.sendRequest` is executed at the end of the scope of the request, no matter what. Knowing that, you might be able to work around it.